# run compass-h5bp project

Tags: ruby, compass-sass, sass, html5boilerplate

I'm new to ruby, please forgive me for this silly question.

I created a simple compass-h5bp project using the command below:

```
create my_project -r compass-h5bp -r html5-boilerplate -u html5-boilerplate --javascripts-dir js --css-dir css

directory my_project/ 
directory my_project/css/ 
directory my_project/js/ 
directory my_project/sass/ 
directory my_project/sass/partials/ 
   create my_project/config.rb 
   create my_project/sass/style.scss 
   create my_project/sass/partials/_base.scss 
   create my_project/sass/partials/_overrides.scss 
   create my_project/sass/partials/_fonts.scss 
   create my_project/sass/partials/_media.scss 
   create my_project/sass/partials/_page.scss 
   create my_project/index.html 
   create my_project/index.html.haml 
   create my_project/js/jquery-1.6.2.js 
   create my_project/js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js 
   create my_project/js/modernizr-2.0.6.min.js 
   create my_project/js/plugins.js 
   create my_project/js/script.js 
   create my_project/404.html 
   create my_project/.htaccess 
   create my_project/crossdomain.xml 
   create my_project/robots.txt 
   create my_project/humans.txt 
   create my_project/apple-touch-icon.png 
   create my_project/apple-touch-icon-57x57-precomposed.png 
   create my_project/apple-touch-icon-72x72-precomposed.png 
   create my_project/apple-touch-icon-114x114-precomposed.png 
   create my_project/apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png 
   create my_project/favicon.ico 
   create my_project/css/style.css
```

now I wonder how to run this simple project via the browser, can some one help me with command?
Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried simply opening `my_project/index.html` in a web browser?

Comment: Yes, but this is not working, it shows only the source.